# não consigo enviar arquivos para o repositorio no github

Tags: github

não consigo ter acesso ao meu repositorio:

faço o seguinte :
vou na pasta e abro o git bash here

```
git --global user.name " Di82Rquant"
git --global user.email "Di82Rquant@gmail.com

git init
 git remote add origin   git@github.com:Di82Rquant/repositorio-teste.git
git pull origin master
```

da essa mensagem :

> The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.253.112)' can't be
>   established. RSA key fingerprint is
>   SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8. Are you sure you
>   want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes Warning:
>   Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.253.112' (RSA) to the list of
>   known hosts. git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

```
git add .
git commit -m " xxxx"
```

depois da :

> *** Please tell me who you are.
>
> Run
>
> git config --global user.email "you@example.com"   git config
>   --global user.name "Your Name"
>
> to set your account's default identity. Omit --global to set the
>   identity only in this repository.
>
> fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got
>   'Di82R@Di82Rquant.(none)')
>
> git push origin master
>
> error: src refspec master does not match any error: failed to push
>   some refs to 'git@github.com:Di82Rquant/repositorio-teste.git'

Quando dou o git init ele cria na pasta um arquivo git, mas não reconhece o meu repositório.

Comment: Tu ta enviando através de ssh, então tu precisa ter gerado uma chave ssh-key previamente. Se tu trocar pra https mudando a url de origin pra `https://github.com/Di82Rquant/repositorio-teste` ele vai pedir o login e senha na hora de enviar mesmo, sem precisar gerar a chave.

Comment: obrigado, consegui,mas infelizmente o patch que o próprio github me deu não funcionava, quando peguei o patch direto da fonte e coloquei .git funcionou

Answer (score 3):

## Erro: permissão negada (publickey)

Uma mensagem de erro "Permission denied" (permissão negada) indica que o servidor rejeitou a sua conexão. Existem diferentes razões para isso acontecer. Os exemplos mais comuns estão descritos abaixo.

#### O comando `sudo` deve ser usado com o Git?

Você não deve usar o comando `sudo` com o Git. Caso você tenha uma razão muito boa para usar `sudo`, assegure-se de usá-lo com todos os comandos (talvez seja melhor usar `su` para obter um shell como root nesse ponto). Se você [gerar chaves SSH](https://help.github.com/pt/articles/generating-an-ssh-key) sem `sudo` e depois tentar usar um comando como `sudo git push`, você não estará usando as mesmas chaves que gerou.

#### Verifique se está conectado ao servidor correto

Sabemos que digitar é difícil. Preste atenção ao que digita; você não conseguirá se conectar a "githib.com" ou "guthub.com". Em alguns casos, uma rede corporativa também pode causar problemas ao resolver o registro DNS.

Insira o segunte comando para confirmar que está conectado ao domínio correto:

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
> OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
> debug1: Lendo dados de configuração /Users/you/.ssh/config
> debug1: Lendo dados de configuração /etc/ssh_config
> debug1: Solicitando opções para *
> debug1: Conectando a github.com [IP ADDRESS] port 22.
```

A conexão deve ser feita na porta 22, a não ser que você esteja substituindo as configurações para usar [SSH na porta HTTPS](https://help.github.com/pt/articles/using-ssh-over-the-https-port).

#### Sempre utilize o usuário "git"

Todas as conexões devem ser feitas como usuário "git", inclusive aquelas para URLs remotas. Se você tentar se conectar com o seu GitHub nome de usuário, ocorrerá um erro:

```
$ ssh -T GITHUB-USERNAME@github.com
> Permissão negada (publickey).
```

Se houver uma falha na conexão ao usar um URL remoto com seu nome de usuário GitHub, você pode [alterar a URL remota para o usuário "git"](https://help.github.com/pt/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url).

Verifique sua conexão digitando:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
> Olá username! Você conseguiu se autenticar...
```

#### Garanta que você tem uma chave que está em uso

1. Abra o terminal.
2. Verifique se você tem uma chave privada gerada e carregada em SSH. Se estiver usando OpenSSH 6.7 ou anterior

```
# iniciar o ssh-agent em segundo plano
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
> Agent pid 59566
$ ssh-add -l
> 2048 a0:dd:42:3c:5a:9d:e4:2a:21:52:4e:78:07:6e:c8:4d /Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

Se estiver usando OpenSSH 6.8 ou posterior:

```
# iniciar o ssh-agent em segundo plano
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
> Agent pid 59566
$ ssh-add -l -E md5
> 2048 MD5:a0:dd:42:3c:5a:9d:e4:2a:21:52:4e:78:07:6e:c8:4d /Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

O comando `ssh-add` deverá imprimir uma string longa com números e letras. Caso isso não aconteça, você deverá [gerar uma nova chave SSH](https://help.github.com/pt/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) e associá-la a GitHub.

> **Dica:** Na maioria dos sistemas, as chaves privadas padrão
>   (`~/.ssh/id_rsa`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa` e `~/.ssh/identity`) são automaticamente
>   adicionadas ao agente de autenticação SSH. Não há necessidade de
>   executar `ssh-add path/to/key`, a não ser que você substitua o nome do
>   arquivo ao gerar uma chave.

**[Obter mais detalhes](https://help.github.com/pt/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey#getting-more-details)**

Você também pode verificar a chave que está sendo usada tentando se conectar a `git@github.com`:

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
> ...
> debug1: Arquivo de identificação /Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
> debug1: Arquivo de identificação /Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
> debug1: Arquivo de identificação /Users/you/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
> debug1: Arquivo de identificação /Users/you/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
> ...
> debug1: Autenticações que podem prosseguir: publickey
> debug1: Próximo método de autenticação: publickey
> debug1: Tentando chave privada: /Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa
> debug1: Tentando chave privada: /Users/you/.ssh/id_dsa
> debug1: Não há mais métodos de autenticação para tentar.
> Permissão negada (publickey).
```

Nesse exemplo, não temos nenhuma chave SSH para usar. "-1" ao final das linhas "arquivo de identificação" indica que o SSH não conseguiu encontrar um arquivo para usar. Mais adiante, as linhas "Tentando chave privada" também indicam que o arquivo não foi encontrado. Se existisse um arquivo, as linhas seriam respectivamente "1" e "Apresentando chave pública":

```
$ ssh -vT git@github.com
> ...
> debug1: arquivo de identificação /Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
> ...
> debug1: Autenticações que podem prosseguir: publickey
> debug1: Próximo método de autenticação: publickey
> debug1: Apresentando chave pública RSA: /Users/you/.ssh/id_rsa
```

#### Verifique se a chave pública está associada à sua conta

Forneça sua chave pública a GitHub para estabelecer uma conexão segura.

1. Abra o terminal.
2. Inicie o SSH agent em segundo plano.

```
$ eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
> Agent pid 59566
```

3. Encontre e anote a impressão digital da chave pública. Se estiver usando OpenSSH 6.7 ou anterior:

```
$ ssh-add -l
> 2048 a0:dd:42:3c:5a:9d:e4:2a:21:52:4e:78:07:6e:c8:4d /Users/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

Se estiver usando OpenSSH 6.8 ou posterior:

```
$ ssh-add -l -E md5
> 2048 MD5:a0:dd:42:3c:5a:9d:e4:2a:21:52:4e:78:07:6e:c8:4d /Users/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)
```

4. No canto superior direito de qualquer página, clique na foto do seu perfil e clique em **Configurações**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

5. Na barra lateral de configurações do usuário, clique em **Chaves SSH e GPG**.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

6. Compare a lista de chaves SSH com a saída do comando `ssh-add`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso não consiga ver sua chave pública em GitHub, será necessário [adicionar a chave SSH a GitHub](https://help.github.com/pt/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) para associá-la ao seu computador.

> **Aviso:** se você encontrar uma chave SSH com a qual não esteja
>   familiarizado em GitHub, delete-a imediatamente e entre em contato com
>   [Suporte do GitHub](https://support.github.com/contact) ou [Suporte do GitHub Premium](https://premium.githubsupport.com/) para obter ajuda. Uma
>   chave pública desconhecida pode indicar um possível problema de
>   segurança. Para obter mais informações, consulte "[Revisar as chaves
>   SSH](https://help.github.com/pt/articles/reviewing-your-ssh-keys)".

## Fonte

https://help.github.com/pt/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: obrigado, consegui,mas infelizmente o patch que o próprio github me deu não funcionava, quando peguei o patch direto da fonte e coloquei .git funcionou